# OCI8 is not displaying results

Tags: php, oci8

I am doing a migration from an old VM to a new VM but due to security issues, I cannot clone the old VM and have to setup OCI8 and cannot use pecl. I have installed and it displays as a module but the queries are not displaying when the code is executed. The code works fine on the old server but will not work on the newer VM. I been looking at all the settings and PATHs but I am unable to figure out what other settings that I am missing. It displays on php -l command in the console and shows up in the phpinfo() page and also what else am I missing to make this work? I am using an older version of PHP 5.4.16 and OCI8 2.0.8 the echo path for instantclient is also set version 11.2 and runtime is 19.8.0.0.0 thanks for any help

Comment: Do some debugging.  Check the web server error log.  Run a query script with `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` and appropriate error handling after each OCI8 call to see what errors OCI8 gives.

Comment: Thanks, for that I was able to find the issue with it. The issue was with the TNS naming thanks!